# passing variable to PayPal which isn't a set amount

Tags: asp.net, web, paypal, e-commerce

How do you pass a variable to PayPal which isn't a set amount. e.g send the 'GrandTotal' from the basket rather than just entering an amount such as 50.00 in asp.net.

Comment: "which isn't a set amount" - at the time you're submitting, how is it *not* a set amount?  If you're able to send a static value (50.00), you should be able to send your basket total the same way.

Comment: I mean rather than inputting the actual amount myself such as 50.00, i mean picking up the variable "GrandTotal" from my basket and using that value (which could be different each time). Is this possible can you enter the variable into the following line of code?

 <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="grandtotal">

Answer (score 0):

Paypal offers a way to transfer data from third party carts:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_howto_checkout_outside

Essentially your server will have to generate input fields with value and post to Paypal and Paypal will read the data and recreate the cart on their end.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>

how do you change value 0.00 to a variable such as "GrandTotal"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with [Payments Standard](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview) I would go with the [Cart Upload Command method](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload).

If you're comfortable with web service API's I'd recommend using [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf).  It gives you more direct access to the system and allows you to customize things however you need.

Either way you can accomplish your goal.